# CSS Value Equals Another Value

Tags: javascript, css

I am wondering if there is a supported method in CSS to check if the value of an attribute equals the value of another attribute. For example:

```
<div foo="value" bar="value"></div>
```

I would be looking for something similar to this advanced selector

```
div[foo=value][bar=value] {
    font-size:16px;
}
```

Instead of manually checking the value of each, I am looking to just see if they equate, so something like

```
div[foo]==[bar] {
    font-size:16px;
}
```

I don't know of any way to do this, nor have I found any methods by searching the Googlebox.  I suspect Javascript would probably be the way to go

Is there any supported method to check this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such option in CSS. You cannot equal attributes values of other elements. The only thing You can do, is to use JavaScript/jQuery or something on the server-side language.

Example (jQuery):

```
if($('div.example').attr('foo') === $('div.example').attr('bar')) {
    $('div.example').css('fontSize', '16px');
}
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking was going to be required, was just checking if there was some minimally-known selector for this.  Thank you!

Comment: @BryanZwicker Not a problem. Glad to help ;).

Comment: @BryanZwicker And, You could correct proper answer for Your question ;). Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I am doing so. There was a time limit :)

Answer (score 1):

CSS doesn't have any such option.

Answer (score 1):

css only wont help here, you can use javascript and the data-tags

https://jsfiddle.net/2weeqc42/

```
<div data-foo="foo" data-bar="foo">div content 1</div>
<div data-foo="foo" data-bar="bar">div content 2</div>
```

2 divs with the data-tags - in div 1 the values are the same

```
$('div').each(function(){
    if ($(this).data("foo") === $(this).data("bar")){
        $(this).css("color","red"); // or do something else
    }
})
```

i loop through the divs and check if the content of the data-tags is the same - only the first get colored red